# "Cloud Datastore" permission for Google Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

While setting permissions for a new Google Compute Engine VM instance, I noticed that "Cloud Datastore" is a service I can grant my VM access to.

As far as I can tell, `remote_api` and the Python Protobuf Datastore API both use service accounts, which bypass VM permissions.

Does Google have any Datastore libraries that support VM-permission-based authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There's also the [Cloud Datastore API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/) which can be accessed quite easily with [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python#google-cloud-datastore), *Python idiomatic client for Google Cloud Platform services*. Specifically its [datastore client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/datastore-client.html) *a convenience wrapper for invoking APIs/factories w/ a dataset ID* same as cloud project id.